# Upload csv file to S3 bucket from static webpage

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, static-html

I'm trying to create an upload webpage to put csv files in a S3 bucket.
I followed the tutorial from their website. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/

I modified the method to accept parameter filename. Everything works fine but can't find the way to upload file from html to S3.

I'm usual a backend pythonist and google to change this webpage/js, but I didn't manage to solve it.

I tried to change from reader.readAsDataURL(file) to reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8'), also data:image/jpg to data:text/csv or text/plain but on line that requires "includes" returns "length: false"

```
console.log('length: ', e.target.result.includes('data:image/jpeg'))
```

**Down you can find my new code, if you can redirect me to some clues of how can I send csv file and also "?filename=original filename" in API, I'll really love you :).**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload file to S3</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.2.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <h1>S3 Uploader Test</h1>

    <div v-if="!file">
        <h2>Select a file</h2>
        <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <img :src="file" />
        <button v-if="!uploadURL" @click="removeFile">Remove file</button>
        <button v-if="!uploadURL" @click="uploadFile">Upload file</button>
    </div>
    <h2 v-if="uploadURL">Success! File uploaded to bucket.</h2>
</div>

<script>
    const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1000000

    /* ENTER YOUR ENDPOINT HERE */

    const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://<smth>.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/uploads'
    // e.g. https://ab1234ab123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/uploads

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            file: '',
            uploadURL: ''
        },
        methods: {
            onFileChange (e) {
                let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files
                if (!files.length) return
                this.createFile(files[0])
            },
            createFile (file) {
                // var image = new Image()
                let reader = new FileReader()
                reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    //console.log(e.target.result)
                    console.log('length: ', e.target.result.includes('data:/csv'))
                     if (!e.target.result.includes('data:text/csv')) {
                       return alert('Wrong file type', e.target.result)
                    }
                    if (e.target.result.length > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                        return alert('File is loo large.')
                    }
                    this.file = e.target.result
                }
                // reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            },
            removeFile: function (e) {
                console.log('Remove clicked')
                this.file = ''
            },
            uploadFile: async function (e) {
                console.log('Upload clicked')
                // Get the presigned URL
                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: API_ENDPOINT+'?filename='+'last.csv'
                })
                console.log('Response: ', response)
                console.log('Uploading: ', this.file)
                let binary = atob(this.file.split(',')[1])
                let array = []
                for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i))
                }
                let blobData = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'text/csv'})
                console.log('Uploading to: ', response.uploadURL)
                const result = await fetch(response.uploadURL, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: blobData
                })
                console.log('Result: ', result)
                // Final URL for the user doesn't need the query string params
                this.uploadURL = response.uploadURL.split('?')[0]
            }
        }
    })
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #20262E;
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    #app {
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 20px;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #logo {
        width: 100px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    h1, h2 {
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    a {
        color: #42b983;
    }
    img {
        width: 30%;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are creating a static web site that uses script tags, consider using the **AWS SDK for JavaScript** to place objects into an Amazon S3 bucket. Uploading objects is covered in the *AWS Developer Guide for JavaScript SDK Version 3*.

[Uploading photos to Amazon S3 from a browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

(Of course for your use case, replace photo files with a CSV file).

Comment: Thanks for redirecting. After more few hours :) learnt more Vue.JS and solved my issue. 

> Completely renounce to '''"result.includes('"'''' - I suppose is something related to image files.

> Create a variable in vue.js variable definition and got the name from file.name

> And the blobData I defined as '''let blobData = new Blob([this.file], {type: 'text/csv'})'''

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @smac2020 for direction, still pretty useful I didn't have the chance to study it more.
After few hours of vue.js learning,  made this working code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload file to S3</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.2.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <h1>S3 Uploader Test</h1>

    <div v-if="!file">
        <h2>Select a file</h2>
        <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <div>File {{ name }} loaded </div>
        <button v-if="!uploadURL" @click="removeFile">Remove file</button>
        <button v-if="!uploadURL" @click="uploadFile">Upload file</button>
    </div>
    <h2 v-if="uploadURL">Success! File uploaded to bucket.</h2>
</div>

<script>
    const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1000000

    /* ENTER YOUR ENDPOINT HERE */
    const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://<smth>.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/uploads'
    // e.g. https://ab1234ab123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/uploads

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            file: '',
            uploadURL: '',
            name: ''
        },
        methods: {
            onFileChange (e) {
                let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files
                if (!files.length) return
                this.createFile(files[0])
            },
            createFile (file) {
                let reader = new FileReader()
                this.name = file.name
                console.log(this.name)
                reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    if (e.target.result.length > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                        return alert('File is loo large.')
                    }
                    this.file = e.target.result
                }
            },
            removeFile: function (e) {
                console.log('Remove clicked')
                this.file = ''
            },
            uploadFile: async function (e) {
                console.log('Upload clicked', this.name)
                // Get the presigned URL
                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: API_ENDPOINT+'?filename='+this.name
                })
                console.log('Response: ', response)
                let blobData = new Blob([this.file], {type: 'text/csv'})
                console.log('Uploading to: ', response.uploadURL)
                const result = await fetch(response.uploadURL, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: blobData
                })
                console.log('Result: ', result)
                // Final URL for the user doesn't need the query string params
                this.uploadURL = response.uploadURL.split('?')[0]
            }
        }
    })
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #20262E;
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    #app {
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 20px;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #logo {
        width: 100px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    h1, h2 {
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    a {
        color: #42b983;
    }
    img {
        width: 30%;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```